# How to make a table occupies all page in 2 column page format {ieeeconf}

Tags: tables, multicolumn, ieeeconf

I would like to create a table that covers 2 columns instead of 1 in 2 column page format. The code I wrote

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcccccc}
\hline
Z & \multicolumn{6}{c}{TExt} \\ \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\ \hline
& & \multicolumn{4}{c}{nRMSE(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
1        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
2        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
3        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
4        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
5        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
Overall        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
 \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image: the text is not covering whole page]

Table seems cover both columns but text is not covering.
Is there a way to make text to cover the whole page also?

I want to see my table as in the example below
[image: desired]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could add more content. Or maybe change to a tabularx used the right way (with a `X` column).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what do you mean by with a X column?

Comment: See the [`tabularx` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf). But I would not recommend to expand the table to the whole width. It wouldn't look good and would be hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that works and uses (a) booktabs (you loaded, but ignored it) and (b) tabularx the right way (you used one without `X` column). But I don't say that this style will be better (as it harms readability if the table has too much stretched white space).

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Z & \multicolumn{6}{c}{TExt} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\\midrule
& & \multicolumn{4}{c}{nRMSE(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
1        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
2        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
3        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
4        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
5        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\
Overall        & 10  & 11 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15 \\\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, this is working fine. I will consider the readability as you mentioned.